# Cannot read property 'then' of undefined in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I have no idea why I encountered that error in my code.

```
    fineOneBySocialLogin(profile).then(function (user) {

    }, function (err) {
        return done(err, null);
    })



var fineOneBySocialLogin = function (req, res) {
    auth.findOne({ username: req.emails[0].value }).then(function (user) {
        if (!user) {
            console.log('testing 1');
            var userForm = {};
            userForm = {
                email: req.emails[0].value
            };
            user.createUser(userForm).then(function(user) {
                if (user) {
                    console.log('testing 2');
                    auth.findOne({ username: req.emails[0].value }).then(function (user) {
                        if (user) {
                            console.log('testing 3');
                            return user;
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        } else {
            return user;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add `return before auth.findOne` in the second raw.

```
var fineOneBySocialLogin = function (req, res) {
  return  auth.findOne({ username: req.emails[0].value }).then(...
```

Answer (score 3):

should be 
`return    auth.findOne(...`